# How to jump to next form input field

Tags: javascript, forms, input

I want the cursor to jump to the next input field when pressing enter.

If I remove the "select"-tag from the code below it works. But I need it to work with the "select"-tag. What is wrong with my javascript?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function jump(elmnt,content)
{
if (event.keyCode == 13)
    {
    next=elmnt.tabIndex
    document.jumpForm.elements[next].focus()
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>This script automatically jumps to the next input field when the current field's maxlength has been reached.</p>
<form name="jumpForm">
<select style = "border: 4px solid red;" name = "typ" tabindex="0">
                        <option value = "+">Zugang</option>
                        <option value = "-">Abgang</option>
                        <option value = "b">Bruchware</option>
                        <option value = "x">Lagerort löschen</option>
                    </select>
<input size="3" tabindex="1" onkeyup="jump(this,this.value)">
<input size="3" tabindex="2" onkeyup="jump(this,this.value)">
<input size="3" tabindex="3" onkeyup="jump(this,this.value)">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i added

-eventlistener

-tabindex+1

-onkeyup to select

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function jump(elmnt,content)
    {
    document.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {

    if (event.keyCode == 13)
        {

        next=elmnt.tabIndex+1;
        document.jumpForm.elements[next].focus()
        }

    });
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>This script automatically jumps to the next input field when the current field's maxlength has been reached.</p>
    <form name="jumpForm">
    <select style = "border: 4px solid red;" name = "typ" tabindex="0" onkeyup="jump(this,this.value)">
                            <option value = "+">Zugang</option>
                            <option value = "-">Abgang</option>
                            <option value = "b">Bruchware</option>
                            <option value = "x">Lagerort löschen</option>
                        </select>
    <input size="3" tabindex="1" onkeyup="jump(this,this.value)">
    <input size="3" tabindex="2" onkeyup="jump(this,this.value)">
    <input size="3" tabindex="3" onkeyup="jump(this,this.value)">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because now the element's tab indexes and the array indexes are identical, e.g. the first text input has a tabIndex of 1 and is the second input field, so it also has the index 1 in the `jumpform.elements` array. If you remove the `select`, it becomes the first element, thus the next element now has the index of 1 and gets focused.

Try `next = elmnt.tabIndex + 1;`.